# Probability of getting white ball

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**If there are *x* black balls, *y* white balls and *z* red balls in a bag , *r* balls are drawn without replacement and now after this one more ball is drawn . What is the probability of this ball being white ??**

**Given : *r <(x+y)***

How to solve this? What approach do you recommend for these kind of questions ?

Comment: It's $y/(x+y+z)$. Just imagine arranging the $(x+y+z)$ balls in a row in a uniformly random order, and asking for the colour of the ball at position $(r+1)$. This is just an outline; someone may post a clearer answer.

Comment: so it is independent of r ??

Comment: $0$ if $ r \geq y $.

Comment: @hjpotter92 How?? if r =z and r>=y and only red balls are taken out then it is not zero ???

Comment: What I meant was, you can find a lower limit and an upper limit of the probability. Exact probability can not be computed without knowing what $r$ holds.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Won't it even depend on r ??

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You should post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: @SayanPaul: Yes, it won't depend on $r$ (as long as $r < x + y + z$ of course).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one else is posting an answer...

Original setting: you draw balls one-by-one, without replacement, until you've drawn $r$ balls, and then one more ball.

Instead imagine the following modified setting: as you draw balls one-by-one, you place them in a row, in order (i.e., placing the latest drawn one at the end of the current row). Even after you've drawn $r+1$ balls, continue to draw balls one-by-one till all $x+y+z$ balls are exhausted.

We can see the following:

- The probability that the last ball drawn in the original setting is white, is the same as the probability that the ball at position $r+1$ in the row in the modified setting is white (in fact it's the same ball).
- The final row formed at the end, in the modified setting, is a uniformly random permutation of the $(x+y+z)$ balls.

Therefore, the answer, the probability that the ball at position $r+1$ is white, is $$\dfrac{y}{x+y+z}$$ as all balls are equally likely at that position, and there are $y$ white balls among the $x+y+z$ balls.

Note that this does not depend on $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine $r=1$.  The probability of drawing a white after drawing a single ball is

$$P(W|B) P(B) + P(W|W) P(W) + P(W|R) P(R)$$

which is

$$\frac{y}{x+y+z-1} \frac{x}{x+y+z} + \frac{y-1}{x+y+z-1} \frac{y}{x+y+z} + \frac{y}{x+y+z-1} \frac{z}{x+y+z}$$

which simplifies to $y/(x+y+z)$.  This experiment may be applied recursively, say $r$ times, so that the probability sought remains at  $y/(x+y+z)$ until there is a possibility of no more of a certain color of ball, i.e. $r \le \min\{x,y,x\}$.

Comment: so what will be the answer if _**r > min{x,y,z}**_ ?

Comment: I gave you the answer when $r \gt \min\{x,y,z\}$.  When $r \lt \min\{x,y,z\}$, however, it gets messy.  By then, you are $r$ levels down in a recursive tree and must sum across it; some of the branches of this tree have probabilities of zero which remain zero as more balls are drawn.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer ..
so for r < _min{x,y,z}_ , can you tell me more about the recursive procedure and how to come about a proper solution perhaps .

Comment: You don't need $r \le \min {x, y, z}$ for the answer to hold. :-)